# Getting Value from Object Attribute in separate file

Tags: python, memory, attributes, memory-address

I am attempting to access a attribute from an object I have created in a separate python file.

I have tried the following code:

```
print(self.GENOME[0][0].x)
```

where `self.GENOME[0][0]` is the object memory address.

However, I get

> AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'x'

agent.py:

```
 import neuron

 #Creates an array of custom shape (3,4,3) and assigns unique object 
 #address

 for ii in range(len(_Topology)):
      _Genome[ii] = [{neuron.Neuron()} for i in range(_Topology[ii]+1)]

 #Calls object variable
 print(self.GENOME[0][0].x)
```

neuron.py:

```
class Neuron:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 50
```

Comment: Why are you using a set to contain a single instance of that class?

Comment: This code is going to be used for a neural network. in reality the Neuron is going to contain MANY weight values. these weight values must be able to be accessed by other Neuron objects. However I thought I would begin with a simple example because i wanted t omit any unnecessary complexity.

Comment: That does not explain why you are using a set to contain a single instance of `Neuron`: I'm asking about this - `{neuron.Neuron()} ...`

Comment: In previous iteration of my code I would have all the weight values of a neuron in the dictionary. however since I now plan on storing all the neuron values in a separate object, I suppose i should be using an array apposed to a dictionary.

Comment: I posted an answer explaining why you are getting the error and how you might mitigate that if you keep your current process. It really doesn't make much sense to create a set of just one object - if you change your process my answer is moot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_Genome[ii]` contains a list that contains a set of at least on `Neuron` instance. Simplifying, you can make it like this:

```
>>> a = [{Neuron()} for _ in [1,2]]
>>> a
[{<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002CAFF28>}, {<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002CAFF60>}]
>>> q = [a]
>>> q
[[{<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002CAFF28>}, {<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002CAFF60>}]]
>>>
```

If you print `_Genome`, it will look something like that - I'm assuming `_Genome` is *list-like* | `q` above should be analogous to `_Genome`.

Indexing into it looks like this

```
>>> q[0]
[{<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002CAFF28>}, {<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002CAFF60>}]
>>> type(q[0])
<class 'list'>
>>> q[0][0]
{<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002CAFF28>}
>>> type(q[0][0])
<class 'set'>
>>>
```

Set behaviour is [well documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) - just like most of Python.

One way to access the contents of a set is with a for loop

```
>>> for thing in q[0][0]:
    print(thing.x)
50
>>>
```

Another way to access the contents of a set is with the `pop()` method but this will remove an **arbitrary** item from the set.  I don't think you really want this - you have no control over which item you get if there are more than one and the original set has one less item.

```
>>> x = [[{Neuron()},{Neuron}]]
>>> t = x[0][0].pop()
>>> t
<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002C2F2E8>
>>> t.x
50
>>> x
[[set(), {<class '__main__.Neuron'>}]]
>>>
```

You could also make a list from the set and use indices to access the contents of the list.

```
>>> q
[[{<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002CAFF28>}, {<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002CAFF60>}]]
>>> z = list(q[0][0])
>>> z
[<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002CAFF28>]
>>> z[0].x
50
>>>
```

---

All of that seems overly complicated and you would probably be better off changing the way you contain the `Neuron` instances. I have no idea if this is feasible for you. Just dispense with the set containing a single instance:

```
>>> a = [Neuron() for _ in [1,2]]
>>> a
[<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002C2FDD8>, <__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002CD00B8>]
>>> q = [a]
>>> q[0][0]
<__main__.Neuron object at 0x0000000002C2FDD8>
>>> type(q[0][0])
<class '__main__.Neuron'>
>>> q[0][0].x
50
>>>
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much, it finally works! I would up-vote you if i was able, so instead get a hardy handshake *shakes hand*